# How to say Android my app is an email client app?

Tags: android, email

I have developed a little email client app, only to send an email to some contacts
But I don't know how to say Android that my app is an email client. When I click on the email address of my contact, android let me choose to open Gmail or Aquamail (my 2 app installed from Google store), but not my app.

I guess I have to add something in my Manifest file, but I didn't find

Thanks for your help

Comment: `<intent-filter>`. Add to the activity that should do the job.

Comment: I already have tried this <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_EMAIL" /> but it doesn't work

Comment: I have no idea what you tried. Please show complete activity definition from manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Put these intent filters in the Manifest in activity section.

```
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>
                <data android:scheme="mailto"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
                <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: I would be grateful if you make my answer an accepted answer for this question. @Dududu13

Answer (score 0):

OK, it was almost good, but now I cannot get my email address when I click on it
Here's my code,

```
    String recupIndent () {
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        return bundle.getStringArray(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL)[0];
    } else {
        return "";
    }

}
```

Comment: If you have another question, please answer this to explain how you fix THIS question and ask another one